# left derived functors commute with filtered  colimits

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, derived-functors

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an $\mathbf{AB5}$ category with enough projectives and let $F:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}$ be a right exact functor into abelian category that commutes with filtered colimits. What reasonable assumptions should one imposed on $\mathcal{A}$ and $F$ to obtain that letf derived functors of $F$ commute with filtered colimits?

Answer (score 11):

When $\mathcal{B}$ is also AB5, this is the case iff filtered colimits of projectives are $F$-acyclic:

"$\Rightarrow$" If $\{X_i\}$ is a filtered system of projectives, then
$$(L^* F)(\mathrm{colim}_i X_i) = \mathrm{colim}_i (L^* F)(X_i) = 0,$$
i.e. $\mathrm{colim}_i X_i$ is $F$-acyclic.

"$\Leftarrow$" If $\{X_i\}$ is some filtered system, choose for each $X_i$ some projective resolution $(P_{\bullet})_i \to X_i$. By assumption and since $\mathcal{A}$ is AB5, $\mathrm{colim} (P_{\bullet})_i$ is a $F$-acylic resolution of $\mathrm{colim}_i X_i$, so that we can use it to compute the Left derived functors. It follows (since $\mathcal{B}$ is AB5)

$(L^* F)(\mathrm{colim}_i X_i) = H_*(\mathrm{colim}_i (P_{\bullet})_i) = \mathrm{colim}_i H_*(P_{\bullet})_i) = \mathrm{colim}_i (L^* F)(X_i)$

and this is induced by the canonical morphism $\leftarrow$. $\square$

For example, the tensor product $M \otimes_R - : \mathrm{Mod}(R) \to \mathrm{Ab}$ satisfies this assumption, since filtered colimits of projectives are flat and therefore acyclic with respect to the tensor product. It follows that $\mathrm{Tor}_*(M,-)$ commutes with filtered colimits.

Comment: Martin thank you for your answer. Do you know any usefull criteria when acyclic objects are closed under taking filtered colimits?

Comment: I don't, but I think without any specific choice of $F$ there is no general criterion.

Comment: I wish know a reference about how the morphisms of the filtred system have a (coherent) lifting to a filtred system of projective resolutions.







Comment: @Buschi: What is unclear?

Comment: @Brandenburg 
You deliver the colimit $C_n:=colimi_{i\in I} P_{n, i}$,

I dont understand (my ignorance probabily) how are defined the morphism in the $I$-diagram $(P_{n,i})_{i\in I}$ , your proof builds only the objects of this diagram. 

 

Comment: Colimit is functorial.

Comment: Of course, but the quest is about the functoriality  of projective  resolution: you make for any $X_i$ a projective resolution chain complex $(P_{n, i})$,  how do you extend the morphisms of the diagram $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ to morphisms of chain complexes  in $I$-coherent way? In short words I  wish know how do you get (for any n) a diagram: 

$(P_{n,i})_{i\in I}$   *natural in $i\in I$*.



Sorry for mine bad English, and for boring you again.  

Comment: Ah, this is the fundamental lemma of homological algebra.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Sorry for my ignorant. Is there any reference for that fundamental lemma? I know that one can obtain lift a map $A'\to A$ to a map $\mathbf P'\to\mathbf P$, where $\mathbf P'\to A'$ and $\mathbf P\to A$ are projective resolutions. And Horseshoe lemma is a related fact. However, I don't know the counterpart for arbitrary filtered system.

Comment: @Frank: Just do it for any morphism in $I$ individually. Because of the uniqueness of the lifts (up to homotopy), you obtain the "$I$-coherent lifting" you're searching for.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt Is up to homotopy enough, namely it's not a commutative diagram in the chain complex category, but in the chain complex homotopy category? In Cartan and Eilenberg, pp100, Lemma 9.5, they construct a special projective resolution for a direct system of modules, in fact, a special *natural* free resolution. Maybe something like Godement injective resolution, just as in Sergio's answer mentioned in Weibel's book, should work.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a comment on some aspect of the Brandenburg answere. 
I wish elucidate the aspect about the $I$-naturality of projective resolutions:

considerind a example of a single morphism $f: A\to B$ and two projective resolution $P_\ast\to A$ and  $Q_\ast\to B$ then is a well knowed fundamental lemma of homological algebrathat exist (homotopically unique) a extentions of $f$ to the (augmented) chain complexes.
In the basic homological algebra text there is also the example of a resolution of exat sequences.

But what if insted a single morphism (or a exat sequence) we consider a small diagram?

From  Weibel, "An introduction to homological algebra", 2.3.13 on p.43 (I see it from [link text](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6776/how-to-construct-pair-of-adjoint-functors-from-category-a-to-category-a-dcategor)) follow that $\mathcal{A}^I$ has enought projectives, but isnt clear if for a projective $P\in \mathcal{A}^I$ each $P(i)\in \mathcal{A}$ is projective as we need in the context of the above Brandenburg proof

(this is true if for any $i\in I$  the right Kan extention of the $i$-valutation $v(i): \mathcal{A}^I\to \mathcal{A}$ is exact, I dont know if this follow from the "$I$ is filtrant" hypothesis).

From the book  "Theory of Categories (BArry Mitchell)  cor.7.6 p. 138,   let  $T_i: \mathcal{A}^I\to \mathcal{A}$ ($i\in I$) the $i$-valuation, and $S_i$ its left adjuction (the left Kan extention), now for a projective $P\in \mathcal{A}$ the object $S_i(P)(j),\ j\in I$ is a sum of copies of $P$ (see the Weibel reference above) then is projective. THe above  corollary assert that  projectives of $\mathcal{A}^I$ are objects of the form $\bigoplus_{i\in I}S_i(P_i)$ (where $P_i\in \mathcal{A}$ is a prjective) and all its retracts.

This is enought for ensure the existence a projective resolution of a  $(X_i)_i\in \mathcal{A}^I$ with projective arguments.